# APEX CPU Limit. Use maps instead of lists in apex class

Tags: apex

I have created a flow that based on some requirements, finds a list of accounts. The flow then passes this list of accounts and a new account owner (id) to an apex class. The apex class then updates all the accounts with this new owner and also updates each opportunity and each task listed under each activity with the same account owner. This was working fine till I stated updated large number of accounts. I am now hitting APEX CPU Limit. My apex class is shown below. I think I need to use Maps, but I dont know how to. Any ideas on how to rewrite this code to make it more efficient so that I dont run into APEX CPU limits? Thank you

```
public class LCD_AccountinCounty {
    @InvocableMethod(label='Account Owner Update flow' Description='Update Account Object with new owner')
    public static void updateAccountOwner(List<FlowDetail> flowdetails) {

        List<Account> accList = new List<Account>();

        for(FlowDetail fd : flowdetails){
            for(Account acct : fd.accounts){
                acct.OwnerId = fd.newAccountOwnerName;
                acc.Salesperson__c = SalespersonName;
                accList.add(acct);
            }
        }

        update accList;

        List<Opportunity> opportunities = new List<Opportunity>();

        for(Opportunity opp: [SELECT Id, OwnerId, AccountId, Account.OwnerId FROM Opportunity WHERE AccountId IN :accList and StageName !='Closed']){
            opp.OwnerId = opp.Account.OwnerId;

            opportunities.add(opp);

        }

        update opportunities;

        List<Task> activities = new List<Task>();

        for(Task t: [SELECT Id, OwnerId, WhatId, Account.OwnerId FROM Task WHERE WhatId IN :accList]){
            t.OwnerId = t.Account.OwnerId;

            activities.add(t);

        }

        update activities;


    }


    public with sharing class FlowDetail{
        @InvocableVariable
        public List<Account> accounts;

        @InvocableVariable
        public String newAccountOwnerName;

        @InvocableVariable
        public String SalespersonName;

    }

}
```

Comment: You say a "large number of accounts" but how many are we talking about here? More than 200?

Comment: It could 300-600 accounts and then each of those have related opps and tasks. The above class is failing in some cases. What I did now is separate the three updates in different classes, and the flow is calling them one after the other. NOt sure if that will resolve the apex limit. Also, Is there anyway to pass flow inputs to a batch job?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have triggers on these objects that are firing some additional logic?

You can't pass a wrapper class to a batch class.
You can however pass in complex data types using the Queueable interface.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_queueing_jobs.htm

You could move your above code into a Queueable class and enqueue it like below:

```
   public class LCD_AccountinCounty {
        @InvocableMethod(label='...' Description='...')
        public static void updateAccountOwner(List<FlowDetail> flowdetails) {
            AsyncExecutionExample a = new AsyncExecutionExample(flowdetails);
            System.enqueueJob(a);
        }
    }

    public class AsyncExecutionExample implements Queueable {
        public LCD_AccountinCounty.FlowDetail flowdetails;
        public AsyncExecutionExample(LCD_AccountinCounty.FlowDetail flowdetails){
            this.flowdetails = flowdetails;
        }
        public void execute(QueueableContext context) {
            *Old updateAccountOwner code goes here...*      
        }
    }
```